# How to catch HTML tags with regex?

Tags: regex

I've a regex pattern to get some HTML tags in my code. The problem is that the pattern is getting more than just a tag, bringing all the part of code between the first match and the lastest match.

Here is my regex tests:
https://regexr.com/3h073

This is how my current regex looks:

```
<option_(.*)_[0-9]>
```

And in the following text and need two different matches (`<option_teste_2>`,`<option_teste_1>`):

```
<p><br></p><table class="table table-bordered"><tbody><option_teste_2><tr><td><br></td><td><br></td><td><br></td></tr><tr><td><br></td><td><p><input_nome_funcionario><br></p></td><td><option_teste_1><br></td></tr><tr><td><br></td><td><br></td><td><br></td></tr></tbody></table><p><br></p>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Obligatory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/59087

Comment: **Don't**. Period. *But anyway, to fix it on your small example, use `.*?`* Also, your HTML is malformed since there's no close tag for the elements you're searching for.

Comment: @ctwheels this tag will be replaced by another text. Thanks a lot. .*? works fine!

Comment: @MurillodeMorais it works by making the `*` quantifier *lazy*. This basically means it'll match `.` (any character) `*` (any number of times) `?` (but as few as possible)

Comment: Try http://regexr.com/3h07i